# Imágenes en Maven

Tags: imagen, maven, glassfish

Quería saber si alguien me puede dar un ejemplo o indicar cómo hacer para mostrar imagen/es desde fuera de mi proyecto.

Mi proyecto es web hecho en maven y glassfish quiero dar una ubicación en una carpeta exterior (la ubicación ya la generé) pero al pasarle el id del widket al html y agregarlo no me muestra la imagen.

```
@Override
    public void ArmarRuta(IMostrarImagenView view){

        String url = "/datos/firebird/imagenes/";
        String carpeta = view.getCodArt();
        String destinoImg = url+carpeta;

        BuscarImagenes(view, new File(destinoImg));

    }////Aca armo el la ruta

@Override
    public void BuscarImagenes(IMostrarImagenView view ,File dir){

        java.io.File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if(listFile != null){
           for(int i = 0; i<listFile.length; i++){
               if(listFile[i].isDirectory()){>>>>Busco todos los archivos que esta en la carpeta 

                   BuscarImagenes(view, (File) listFile[i]);

               }else{
                       view.setImg(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());>>> guardo la direccion completa con el archivo en un String (/datos/firebird/imagenes/000000000002305/Img1-200x200.png)                 
               }

           } 
        }

    }
 ///Acá agrego la dirección a la variable img y lo agrego al formulario

add(new WebMarkupContainer("img1").add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("src", img)));

<<<<En el HTML>>>>
agrego el id del wicket 
<img alt="img1" wicket:id="img1"/>
```

¿Habría alguna forma de almacenar en el glassfish las imágenes para directamente buscarlas allí?

Comment: Podrias agregar lo que intentaste, realizaste alguna configuracion en glassfish para servir contenido estatico desde otra ubicacion? De que manera estas enlazando el contenido estatico en tu html?

Comment: Podrias intentar lo que indican en la siguiente url (en ingles): http://harkiran-howtos.blogspot.cl/2009/08/map-external-directory-into-glassfish.html